# Rename all column names inside a SQL table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table on snowflake which has more than 100 columns, and I would like to add a suffix '_LA' to all the column names. Is there any easy way to do this in sql?

Answer (score 1):

this script produce alter command for all columns of given schema.table name:

```
  select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ' RENAME COLUMN ' || column_name || ' TO _LA' || column_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema ilike 'schema' -- put your schema name here
           and table_name ilike 'table'  -- put your table name here
    order by ordinal_position;
```